# Achieving Off-axis projection

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, openframeworks

I am trying to get an off-axis projection effect where the screen's content change as per the position of the user. This is similar to what is being done here in this video:
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Jd3-eiid-Uw

I am not sure why off-axis projection is the appropriate method to achieve the above effect. There are two methods that I seem to think of here: 1) Using glFrustum, 2) Using lookAt()
In the application above, the 'camera' basically moves as per the user's position.
The `glFrustum` coordinates of (`left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `near`, `far`) for the perspective projection are being given to change the objects on the screen as they would appear from a different position when the user moves.

At the same time, I find this very similar to translating a camera with the user's position and then giving a `gluLookAt(centerPosition)` for the camera to `lookAt` the center. But I didn't get the required effect with this one and wanted to know why this was happening.

[image]

What is the difference between the above two?

The off-axis projection is achieved by the following in OpenGL:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity();            
    glFrustum(fNear*(-fFov * ratio + headX),  
              fNear*(fFov * ratio + headX),  
              fNear*(-fFov + headY),  
              fNear*(fFov + headY),  
              fNear, fFar);  
          
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    gluLookAt(headX*headZ, headY*headZ, 0, headX*headZ, headY*headZ, -1, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,headZ);
```

What is the point of *gluLookAt(...)* above and not when I was trying to use a camera and was just giving it a `lookAt point` as the center of the screen?

Comment: With your `glFrustum` approach, you end up with a skewed frustum. With your `gluLookAt` approach, you don't.

Comment: @sftrabbit : Can you please explain this in a little more detail. I have been really trying to understand this but there's very little I could comprehend with my little knowledge. Why would a skewed matrix give more of an illusion of 3D perspective than changing lookAt?

Comment: Take a look at the diagram on the right. You have the viewing plane (the little grey square) aligned perpendicular to the "screen". However, that's not correct for this case. If you use a standard perspective projection and then use `gluLookAt`, the viewing plane will be oriented so that its normal is pointing at the center of the "screen". The `glFrustum` approach keeps the viewing plane perpendicular.

Comment: Maybe this will help a little more. Look at the video you linked to. Imagine you could see the back wall of the virtual room. As the real-world camera (the viewer) moves around, the back wall always stays perpendicular to the TV screen. The projection matrix you use should aim to project from the virtual world on to the TV screen, so it should be projecting onto a perpendicular viewing plane. When you use a normal perspective and `gluLookAt`, it is as though your TV is moving and changing orientation in the world. That's not accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure why off-axis projection is the appropriate method to achieve the above effect.

Because the display screen corresponds to the near plane of the frustum. When you move your head around you're going to look at the screen off-axis. In this way you must reproduce this by doing the same with the projection frustum.

Using lookAt however will rotate the scene, by which the correspondence between near plane and screen plane is lost.